# Irreducible components of algebraic affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to compute the irreducible components of an affine variety $V(U) = V(U_1) \cup V(U_2)$ . I already know that $V(U)$ is irreducible component if and only if the ideal $I(V(U))$ is prime, so, I suppose that I need to decompose the ideal into primes, but I don't know if there exists an algorithm (or an easier way to decompose varieties). Thanks in advance

Comment: For your info, you're asking about affine varieties.  I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but I think  you're asking if there's an algorithm for decomposing an affine variety into irreducible components.  If so, then the answer is probably yes, depending on how general you want to get.  The answer is yes, for example for affine varieties over a field.  I think you should learn some more algebraic geometry in the meantime, but you should look in to computational commutative algebra, Groebner bases in particular.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but the question is not about the definitions, is rather about explicit algorithms to decompose ideals on polynomial rings into prime ideals, to find the irreducible components.

Comment: After passing to the algebraic side (looking at the coordinate ring, or associated spec) the process of primary decomposition or localization are the general tools but I don’t know

Comment: I have read something about primary decomposition in Atiyah-McDonald, but there isn't an explicit algorithm :(

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1030933/520527.

Comment: Well! Thanks :D